What does it mean to be a "new creation"?
In 2 Corinthians 5:17, Paul states that

“if anyone is in Christ, he is a new creation; old things have passed
away; behold, all things have become new.”

How is this phrase understood? Are we to understand this transformation as immediate? Or are we to understand this as progressive?
The verse here speaks about the transformative nature of being “in Christ.” However, believers still struggle with sin even after coming to Christ. This makes me raise the question about the nature and timing of this transformation.
So:

What does it mean to be a "new creation"?
In what way are we "new creations"?


In 2 Corinthians 5:17 new is kaine and  it describes someone who is "in Christ". "he is a new creation" new/kaine.
2 Corinthians 5:17-18 ESV

"Therefore if anyone is in Christ, he is a new creation. The old has passed away; behold, the new has come. 18 All this is from God, who reconciled us to himself and gave us the ministry of reconciliation."

Being reconciled to  God through Christ is different from the "old" covenant which was a passing shadow of the new/kainos covenant.
The new/neas covenant of Hebrews 12:24 is young in age compared with the Mosaic covenant. Just as the young men/neaniskoi of 1 John 2:13 are younger  than the fathers/pateres. Covenants in Hebrews can be seen as young in age and different in quality. Covenant being both neos covenant [Hebrews 12:24] and kainos covenant [Hebrews 8:8] does not make these 2 words mean the same.
In this answer I want to compare new/neos with new/kainos as the flavour of these synonyms comes out when contrasted.
Colossians 3:10

"and have put on the new self, which is being renewed in knowledge after the image of its creator."

Here the neon/self is one that is new in time. The new/neon self is shedding old habits of "anger, wrath, malice, slander" and other practices of the old self [Col 3:8-9]. And taking on new habits through a different way of thinking. Here neon is contrasted with old/palaion practices. Habits  change within the orbit of time.
From Ephesians 2:15-16

"by abolishing the law of commandments expressed in ordinances, that he might create in himself one new man in place of the two, so making peace and might reconcile us both to God in one body through the cross,.. ".

Here the new/kainon man is reconciled to God. This quality is for all however long or short a time since their conversion from  being far off [Eph 2:13] to being brought near by the blood of Christ.
From Hebrews 8:8-9

".. I will establish a new covenant...not like the covenant I made with their  fathers..". [new/kainen]

This new covenant is different in quality. With Moses the 10 Commandments were written on stone but in the new/kainen covenant "I will put my laws into their minds, and write them on their hearts".
From Jeremiah 31:31-34

"for they shall all know me,"

The new creature/creation of 2 Corinthians 5:17 will know the LORD.
The new/kainos person, "he is a new person", belongs  to the new/kainos Jerusalem. Different from the one built on earth as it comes ready built from Heaven Rev 3:12.
From Rev 21:1-2.

"Then I saw a new heaven and a new earth," new/kainon.

The new earth will be different because the curse lifted as now "the dwelling place of God is with man".
[Referring to "Synonyms" by Trench has helped with some references].
For the new creature: "I will remember their sin no more." Jeremiah 31:34

Answer
I go for the “literal” understanding of the phrase “new creation” because that is what is stated in the Scripture.
Again, this is a progressive creation.
I give below my points.
Explanation
Though, externally, a transformation is visible to the onlookers, internally and literally, this is a new creation, a new “begetting” from God!
How?

“In the case of our human fathers, they punished us and we
respected them. How much more, then, should we submit to our
spiritual Father and live! Our human fathers punished us for a short time, as it seemed right to them; but God does it for our own
good, so that we may share his holiness” (Heb 12:9-10).

The above verse says it all!
The human father is a literal father who begets human sons. Yet, they are for “a short time”!
So, if the human father is literal, then the spiritual Father is also literal. And the spiritual begetting from the Father is permanent because we are going to share His holiness for eternity!
The physical human father begets with his physical sperm.
Then, the spiritual divine Father begets with His spiritual sperm!
Please don’t get shocked, Apostle John says the same thing:

“Everyone who has been begotten of God does not sin, because His
seed (“sperma” in Greek and “sperm” in English) abides in him, and he is not able to sin, because he has been born of God” (1 John 3:9).

How does this happen?

“For you did not receive a spirit of slavery again to fear, but you
received a Spirit of υἱοθεσία (a placing as son or sonship
or more correctly begetting) by which we cry, Abba! Father!” (Rom
8:15).

There it is!
“Abba” is the Aramaic equivalent of the English “Dad”. We no longer call God as simply Father, but as our personal “Dad”!
How can we call the Almighty God as our Dad?
Yes, the “seed” (sperma) of God “dwells in” us (Rom 8:9, 11; 1 Cor 3:16). The seed is the Spirit of God which begets us as His own personal sons who call Him Dad.
Again, how does this happen?

“The Spirit itself beareth witness with our spirit, that we are the
children of God” (Rom 8:16).

The Spirit of God we “received”, which “dwells in” us (Rom 8:9, 11; 1 Cor 3:16) works as the seed and joins with our human spirit working as the ovum and a spiritual child is begotten.
Is this just a figurative speaking?
No.

“And if children, also heirs; truly heirs of God, and
joint-heirs of Christ, if indeed we suffer together, that we may also be glorified together” (Rom 8:17).

We are not figurative sons but literally (truly) we are going to inherit whatever belongs to God just as Jesus Christ has already inherited all things of God.
A Progressive Growth
No wonder, Apostle Paul connects this “new creation” to “labor pain” of a pregnant woman:

“My dear children! Once again, just like a mother in childbirth, I
feel the same kind of pain for you until Christ's nature is formed in
you” (Gal 4:19).

It is obvious that Christ’s nature is Son’s nature and hence Scripture says:

“because whom He foreknew, He also predestinated to be conformed to
the image of His Son, for Him to be the First-born among many
brothers” (Rom 8:30).

Jesus Christ is our eldest Brother. He is God in nature. So we need to grow into His full stature before we are glorified:

“And so we shall all come together to that oneness in our faith and in
our knowledge of the Son of God; we shall become mature people,
reaching to the very height of Christ's full stature” (Eph 4:13).

But this will take time. We need time to grow and become mature from babes. We haven’t yet overcome sin!
[This answers the OP’s question, “However, believers still struggle with sin even after coming to Christ.”]
First Babes
Peter says:

“as newborn babes (of Dad God) desire the pure soul-nourishing
milk, that you may GROW by it” (1 Pet 2:2).

Paul says:

“And, brothers, I was not able to speak to you as to spiritual ones,
but as to fleshly ones, as to babes in Christ. I gave you milk to
drink, and not food, for you were not then able, for neither are
you yet able now. For you are yet fleshly. For where among you is
jealousy……” (1 Cor 3:1-3).

See, the spiritual journey begins as babies in Christ after begotten from Dad God. They still struggle with sin!
Salvation is not a one day process! It requires “enduring till the end”.

“for everyone partaking of milk is without experience in the Word of
Righteousness, for he is an infant. But solid food is for those
full grown, having exercised the faculties through habit, for
distinction of both good and bad. Because of this, having left the
discourse of the beginning of Christ, let us be borne on to full
growth, not laying down again a foundation of repentance from dead
works, and of faith toward God, of baptisms, of doctrine, and of
laying on of hands, and of resurrection of dead ones, and of eternal
judgment”. (Heb 5:13-14 to 6:1).

The Real Birth
Once a believer is grown to maturity, to the full stature of Christ after overcoming sin, he will be ready to be “glorified” to the full glory of Christ!

“Beloved, we are God's children now, and what we will be has not yet
appeared (that is, it has not occurred yet but will happen at the
Second Coming); but we know that when He appears (at the Second
Coming) we shall be like him, because we shall see him as he is”
(1 John 3:2).


“So also the resurrection of the dead. It is sown in corruption
(physical), it is raised in incorruption (spiritual). It is sown
in dishonor (physical), it is raised in glory (spiritual). It is
sown in weakness (physical), it is raised in power (spiritual). It
is sown a natural body (physical), it is raised a spiritual
body; there is a natural body, and there is a spiritual body” (1 Cor
15:42-44).

[I don’t find any “figurative” speech in the above verses!]

“But not the spiritual first, but the natural; afterward the
spiritual” (verse 46).


“The first man was out of earth, earthy. The second Man was the Lord
out of Heaven. Such as is the earthy man, such also are the earthy
ones. And such as is the heavenly Man, such also are the heavenly
ones. And as we bore the image of the earthy man, we shall also bear
the image of the heavenly Man” (1 Cor 15:47-48).

Thus we have come a full circle!
Just as we bore the nature and composition of our physical fathers (Heb 12:9-10), we will also bear the Nature and Composition of our Spiritual Dad Father!
Conclusion
A “new creation” is literally a creation of the old man into a new real sons of God.

“Jesus answered them, Has it not been written in your Law, "I said,
you are Elohim"? If He called those Elohim with whom the Word of God
was, and the Scripture cannot be broken” (John 10:34-35).


UV. This was a solid exegesis of the text.

Thank you, Jason. Appreciate your good words.

Quick question.  What about believers who die few months after conversion to Christ. And there was no time for them to grow .?

@FaithMendel – Jesus Christ has said, “..., yet not one sparrow falls to the ground without your Father's consent” (Mat 10:29). Nothing happens without God’s permission. He knows His true children. As any good father would, He will protect His real sons and will give them time to grow. God gives a clue of His power in Isaiah 65:20: “No child will die in infancy; everyone will live to a ripe old age. Anyone a hundred years old will be considered young, and to die younger than that will be considered a curse”. If God can do this in the future world, He can do it now also.

Paul's teaching in 2 Cor 5:17 is part of a wider theme in the NT that was first expounded by Jesus in His famous discussion with Nicodemus recorded in John 3.

3 Jesus replied, “Truly, truly, I tell you, no one can see the kingdom of God unless he is born from above.”
4 “How can a man be born when he is old?” Nicodemus asked. “Can he enter his mother’s womb a second time to be born?”
5 Jesus answered, “Truly, truly, I tell you, no one can enter the kingdom of God unless he is born of water and the Spirit. 6 Flesh
is born of flesh, but spirit is born of the Spirit. 7 Do not be
amazed that I said, ‘You must be born from above.’

Paul also takes up the same theme:

Titus 3:5 - He saved us, not by the righteous deeds we had done, but according to His mercy, through the washing of new birth and renewal by the Holy Spirit.
Rom 6:4 - We were therefore buried with Him through baptism into death, in order that, just as Christ was raised from the dead through the glory of the Father, we too may walk in newness of life.
Rom 6:10, 11 - The death He died, He died to sin once for all; but the life He lives, He lives to God. So you too must count yourselves dead to sin, but alive to God in Christ Jesus.
Rom 6:13 - Do not present the parts of your body to sin as instruments of wickedness, but present yourselves to God as those who have been brought from death to life; and present the parts of your body to Him as instruments of righteousness.
Rom 8:9-11 - You, however, are controlled not by the flesh, but by the Spirit, if the Spirit of God lives in you. And if anyone does not have the Spirit of Christ, he does not belong to Christ. But if Christ is in you, your body is dead because of sin, yet your spirit is alive because of righteousness. And if the Spirit of Him who raised Jesus from the dead is living in you, He who raised Christ Jesus from the dead will also give life to your mortal bodies through His Spirit, who lives in you.

Peter says the same thing:

1 Peter 1:3 - Blessed be the God and Father of our Lord Jesus Christ! According to his great mercy, he has caused us to be born again to a living hope through the resurrection of Jesus Christ from the dead,
Acts 5:20 - “Go, stand in the temple courts and tell the people the full message of this new life.”
etc

One of the central teachings of the NT is the new life in Christ - a spiritual life that is not of the flesh but is from the Spirit.  Further, this new life is not a modification of the old, but a completely new creation as Paul states in 2 Cor 5:17.

Just as God spoke, and everything material in creation instantly came into being, so when God speaks for a spiritual creation to be created, all those he brings to newness of spiritual life (born again from above) are instantly created anew. Those ones are his "new creation" in Christ; the people the text in question refers to.
At that point of God's command, the previously spiritually dead person becomes sanctified - set apart as holy to God. This is an instant change of relationship. The word 'holy', especially in the Hebrew scriptures, does not refer in the first instance to a moral state, but to a relationship. Certain cities, vessels and buildings were decreed by God to be set apart unto him, for holy use. So with these new creatures in Christ - those people are declared by God to be set apart by him, for him, for his glory. This declaration of sanctification denotes a change in relationship that no human can effect of their own desire or effort. Here is how one Protestant scholar puts it, leading up to the meaning of 2 Corinthians 5:17:

"Change in Relationship ... That is one of the great primary
ideas in definitive sanctification: Christians are set apart from a
common to a holy use. They are no longer common or profane. They
belong to God. That in turn is rooted in the idea of redemption. In
redemption we have been bought: therefore we should glorify God in
our bodies and in our spirits (1 Corinthians 6:20). They are for God's
use. Indeed, everything we are and everything we have has been set
apart from a common to a holy use. We are 'separated unto the gospel
of God' (Romans 1:1). God has called us out. He has set us apart. We
are His 'peculiar people' (1 Peter 2:9): his special possession.
Secondly, definitive sanctification means transformation. What
we are is radically altered. Our whole being is changed. Our humanness
undergoes radical transformation. It is put most dramatically in these
New Testament terms: 'If anyone is in Christ, he is a new creation'
(2 Corinthians 5:17). If we are in Christ the 'old man' is crucified,
the 'old man' is dead, the 'old man' is done away with. We become new
creatures in Christ Jesus.
Of course, that does not mean that 'the flesh' is destroyed. Nor does
it mean that there is no indwelling sin or that we have no more
spiritual struggles or spiritual problems. But it does mean that we
are new. We are not the people that we were. The person, the
proclivities, the prejudices and the incapacities that used to mark us
no longer exist.
This poses a serious challenge to much traditional theology, which has
sometimes been too willing to accommodate everything to the notion of
indwelling sin. It has been perilously easy to say in the midst of our
own guilt and our own failings, 'Ah! That's only the Old Man! That's
the Old Adam!'... [But] that old unregenerate person is no longer
there. That man that we used to be cannot be blamed for anything we
do. It is we ourselves, the new man, who sins. It is the regenerate
self." A Faith to Live By, Donald Macleod, pp. 176-7, Mentor, 1998

There is more explanation given in the pages that follow, such as this new, sanctified creation being in union with Christ; this new creation being renewed in the whole man after the image of God, including our thinking being changed because of how we now think; of the responsibilities that derive from this gift of being a new creation. However, enough has been quoted to answer the two-fold question. The most succinct answer I can give is that it means everything to be a new creation in Christ.

2 Corinthians 5:17 is only one fragment within the larger theme developed by Paul in the chapter. I'm using "chapter" to refer to 2Cor 3:7 to 7:1. There were no chapter divisions originally, a singular thought can be continued from the end of one chapter to the beginning of another. It'd prove useful to first analyze 3:12 to 4:6 as such an unbroken line of thought. I've highlighted key moments, and all verses are taken from the ESV.

"Since we have such a hope, we are very bold, not like Moses, who would put a veil over his face so that the Israelites might not gaze at the outcome of what was being brought to an end. But their minds were hardened. For to this day, when they read the old covenant, that same veil remains unlifted, because only through Christ is it taken away. Yes, to this day whenever Moses is read a veil lies over their hearts. But when one turns to the Lord, the veil is removed. Now the Lord is the Spirit, and where the Spirit of the Lord is, there is freedom. And we all, with unveiled face, beholding the glory of the Lord, are being transformed into the same image from one degree of glory to another. For this comes from the Lord who is the Spirit. Therefore, having this ministry by the mercy of God, we do not lose heart. But we have renounced disgraceful, underhanded ways. We refuse to practice cunning or to tamper with God's word, but by the open statement of the truth we would commend ourselves to everyone's conscience in the sight of God. And even if our gospel is veiled, it is veiled to those who are perishing. In their case the god of this world has blinded the minds of the unbelievers, to keep them from seeing the light of the gospel of the glory of Christ, who is the image of God. For what we proclaim is not ourselves, but Jesus Christ as Lord, with ourselves as your servants for Jesus' sake. For God, who said, “Let light shine out of darkness,” has shone in our hearts to give the light of the knowledge of the glory of God in the face of Jesus Christ."

Paul explains that believers of the Lord Christ have a hope that contrasts with the Israelites' of the old covenant. Because of the hardened state of their hearts, they could not gaze at the full glory of God's promises; it was as though a veil was covering it, or covering their faces. Turning to Christ lifts the veil, because we have set our sights on the one whose face portrays the glory, and in doing so are ourselves transformed into that same image of glory. Although not everyone gazes upon this glory, to any who reject its image (Jesus) the veil is still present. To believers though, the "light of the knowledge of the glory of God" shines in our hearts, because it is contained in the face of Christ, whom we serve. Now 4:7 to 5:5.


"But we have this treasure in jars of clay, to show that the surpassing power belongs to God and not to us. We are afflicted in every way, but not crushed; perplexed, but not driven to despair; persecuted, but not forsaken; struck down, but not destroyed; always carrying in the body the death of Jesus, so that the life of Jesus may also be manifested in our bodies. For we who live are always being given over to death for Jesus' sake, so that the life of Jesus also may be manifested in our mortal flesh. So death is at work in us, but life in you. Since we have the same spirit of faith according to what has been written, “I believed, and so I spoke,” we also believe, and so we also speak, knowing that he who raised the Lord Jesus will raise us also with Jesus and bring us with you into his presence. For it is all for your sake, so that as grace extends to more and more people it may increase thanksgiving, to the glory of God. So we do not lose heart. Though our outer self is wasting away, our inner self is being renewed day by day. For this light momentary affliction is preparing for us an eternal weight of glory beyond all comparison, as we look not to the things that are seen but to the things that are unseen. For the things that are seen are transient, but the things that are unseen are eternal. For we know that if the tent that is our earthly home is destroyed, we have a building from God, a house not made with hands, eternal in the heavens. For in this tent we groan, longing to put on our heavenly dwelling, if indeed by putting it on we may not be found naked. For while we are still in this tent, we groan, being burdened—not that we would be unclothed, but that we would be further clothed, so that what is mortal may be swallowed up by life. He who has prepared us for this very thing is God, who has given us the Spirit as a guarantee."

The treasure of the knowledge of God's glory (the face of Christ) shines, but it shines in "jars of clay". We are fragile and go through every sort of affliction and despair, yet never to defeat. That God uses our bodies, which are perishing, to reveal the life of Jesus is a demonstration of His power. His life is revealed by our faith, the faith that moves us to speak of him, since we know that we will both die and live again in concert with our Lord. And as the days go by and our conviction is strengthened, at the same time our bodies deteriorate. But as it is so, as Paul says, the inner renewal that takes places in spite the decay of our outer person not only glorifies God but prepares us for the future renewal of the outer person. How? When we see how God is renewing our inner person, we discern that God not only has the power to but will renew our outer person. The inner renewal is a continuous process and doesn't end when we die, rather it culminates at the time when the outer renewal occurs. Sin is abolished when death is, that is, when the "perishable puts on the imperishable" (1Cor 15:50-56); for as long as we remain in our mortal flesh, we will sin. Paul makes the point that the inner renewal is interlinked with the outer renewal. Now 5:11-21.


"Therefore, knowing the fear of the Lord, we persuade others. But what we are is known to God, and I hope it is known also to your conscience. We are not commending ourselves to you again but giving you cause to boast about us, so that you may be able to answer those who boast about outward appearance and not about what is in the heart. For if we are beside ourselves, it is for God; if we are in our right mind, it is for you. For the love of Christ controls us, because we have concluded this: that one has died for all, therefore all have died; and he died for all, that those who live might no longer live for themselves but for him who for their sake died and was raised. From now on, therefore, we regard no one according to the flesh. Even though we once regarded Christ according to the flesh, we regard him thus no longer. Therefore, if anyone is in Christ, he is a new creation. The old has passed away; behold, the new has come. All this is from God, who through Christ reconciled us to himself and gave us the ministry of reconciliation; that is, in Christ God was reconciling the world to himself, not counting their trespasses against them, and entrusting to us the message of reconciliation. Therefore, we are ambassadors for Christ, God making his appeal through us. We implore you on behalf of Christ, be reconciled to God. For our sake he made him to be sin who knew no sin, so that in him we might become the righteousness of God."

In this chapter, Paul is elaborating on themes he begun in his letter to the Romans (see Romans 5-8).  Such as maintaining the hope in God's glory despite suffering (5:1-5; 8:23-25; 31-39), reconciliation to God through Jesus' righteousness (5:6-19), how it entails dying to sin with Christ and raised to newness of life (5:20-6:11; 7:4-6), notwithstanding the limitations of our dying flesh and the sin that results from it (6:12-7:6), being raised with Christ and conformed to his image (8:10-17; 28-30), how Christ was made like sin so that righteousness could be fulfilled in us (8:2-5), the renewal of creation (8:18-25), and how it all coheres within the ultimate plan of God, which is to restore His family (Romans 8). Everything thus far gives us the context to understand what it means to be a new creation.
Being a new creation refers to how the renewal of the inside brings about the renewal of the outside. God intends to form a people who are competent to inherit the promise of a restored creation (2Cor 4:17). By "creation" it means everything, all of existence. God wants to make the creation a place where he can dwell, and that starts with us. For in our inner person being renewed we produce fruitage; our love, our faith, our patience, our discipline, etc. are built up over the course of our life, as we are conformed into Christ's image. We are furnished towards the obtainment of rulership, of the Kingdom, which is fully established in a renewed creation, of which we are the firstfruits (cf. Jas 1:18, 1Pet 2:4-10). This is what it means to bear the "ministry of reconciliation". Already now we work to restore others to God by preaching the news about Christ, which anticipates our future work of restoration, until all "former things have passed away", when there will be no need for a temple because all of creation is his dwelling place (cf. Rev 21:1-4; 22-27; 22:1-5). This chapter of Paul's letter concludes with 2Cor 6:14-7:1. The new creation, of which all who are in Christ are, is the temple of the living God, His sons and daughters.

I'd like to make a final point about being a "new creation". 2 Corinthians 5:16 says that "we regard no one according to the flesh... though we once regarded Christ according to the flesh, we regard him thus no longer". "Flesh" must refer to mortality, because Christ was initially in a mortal state, having died, but he was resurrected to immortality, thus we no longer regard him according to the flesh. Paul says that we are not to regard each other according to the flesh, after which he says "therefore we are a new creation", with the old having "passed away" (same as how the old heavens and earth and things in it will "pass away"). From this it's clear that being a "new creation" refers to the present renewal of our inner person that is completed at the future renewal of our outer person, when we are no longer mortal. We are a new creation that is being moulded into the new creation. And this is what God does. He uses the current, the seen, to help us grasp the eventual, the unseen, so therefore in all strokes of our walk with Christ our assurance in His promises may increase, until their attainment.

The Apostle Paul's radical change becomes the experience of all born again believers. Once dead, now they are alive. formerly blind, now they see!
Christ makes new creations of those who believe, as real as God made Adam in the beginning. Biblical salvation not only brings something new, but it also subtracts something old.
One's former set of values and his way of thinking disappear. His new outlook on life dictates a new life-style; the old becomes unworthy in his eyes.
So what makes a person a new creation? For one God indwells/lives in the person. 2 Corinthains 6:16-18. God also says He will make His abode in a believer. John 14:23. According to Ephesians 1:13 we are sealed with the Holy Spirit of promise.
James 2:17, "Even so faith, if it has now works, is dead, being by itself. Vs18, But someone may well says, "You have faith, and I have works; show me your faith without the works, and I will show you my faith by my works."

I look in vain for any textual support and I find, instead, two more questions. The last paragraph is irrelevant to the question asked and is a theological issue, not an hermeneutic analysis of the text under consideration.

@NigelJ I deleted the last paragraph.

As an experienced contributor, you're well familiar with the standing guideline from Meta to Show your Work - any answer without substantiation is just an opinion! Help us set a good example for new users joining the site.

This answer starts with three two-sentence paragraphs of boilerplate, then restates the original question So what makes a person a new creation?, makes some systheo-style verse cited ststaments, but never addresses the OP's question about the chagne being immediate or progressive.

@Jesse. I already edited my answer recently and explained what it means to be a "new creation." 2 Corinthains 5:17 is clear that one becomes a new creation the moment he is born again/receives Christ. After that the process of "sanctification" begins/growing in Christ Jesus.

The correct word is "new creature" because in the King James Bible and all preceding English Textus Receptus Bibles (Bishop, Geneva, Webster, Tyndale, etc.) the word is NEW CREATURE.

2nd Corinthians 5:17 Therefore if any man be in Christ, he is a new creature: old things are passed away; behold, all things are become
new.

The Bible teaches that a saved person is a new creature. He is reborn. As such, we should also expect to see a change in conduct.
I have been saved since I was a young child, but from many of my church friends who got saved as adults, they can clearly testify that their lives before salvation were drastically different.
Works salvation false prophets and false religions claim that FAITH ALONE salvation means a license to sin.
Their argument falls flat for two reasons.

It only takes ONE SIN to be guilty of all sins (James 2:10). How could you save yourself by keeping the 10 Commandments? Because you do not have to "live in sin" or "live like the devil" to enter Hell; it only takes one sin.

Saved people SHOULD experience a changed life. The Bible is clear that saved people are NEW creatures.


Compare a rabbit to a tiger. They are two creatures, are they not? Therefore, they live radically different lives. A tiger is carnivore; a rabbit is a herbivore. Most rabbits are mild-mannered creatures; tigers are known to be vicious and tough.
There are more aggressive rabbits (relatively so) and more tame tigers, but even then, there is a drastic difference in how they live.
The same goes for a believer and an unbeliever. The Bible is clear that saved and unsaved people are very different people.
The unsaved person is called a child of wrath in the Bible.

Ephesians 2:1-3 And you hath he quickened, who were dead in trespasses and sins; Wherein in time past ye walked according to the
course of this world, according to the prince of the power of the air,
the spirit that now worketh in the children of disobedience: Among
whom also we all had our conversation in times past in the lusts of
our flesh, fulfilling the desires of the flesh and of the mind; and
were by nature the children of wrath, even as others.

This describes unsaved people.

It can not be politically correct to tell a Christian person, who has been unfortunate enough to be born without legs, that s/he now is a new creation in Christ. A new creation spiritually - yes, but obviously not bodily. For the statement that “all things have become new” to be true it needs to reach full completion in heaven, some time later.

Take an analogy: if a gifted street football player is noticed by Barcelona FC functionaire and he says to the boy: "Come with me to Spain and you will get a new life of a football star, you will become a new person". The boy asks: "'New' in which sense?" "In the sense that you will train every day, and this talent of yours will be honed on a daily basis, and eventually, you will start playing on a world stage and realize that your talent became not just one of the aspects of your wayward life of street playing, but your very breathing, you will realize that without football your life is not even worthy of being called life, for it is through football that you develop your God-given talent". "Oh, I understand that and will follow you to Spain".
Something similar also here: if you make practicing of Christ's commandments your profession and start doing that not as an amateur but as a real adept of the craft, then you will realize that it is impossible without ongoing prayers and ascetic struggles, failures and successes, gradual improvements through more and more intense interaction with divine Grace, which is divine operation, the uncreated divine operation, that transforms your entire life and your entire soul and organism. This is to gradually become a "new creation" on whom sin, the original Adamic and Evic sin, that poisons life of all non-Christians and nominal Christians, has no more power.
But it is impossible to know unless you start practicing, for it is an experiential knowledge, just like romantic love is, for unless you date and kiss your beloved, read 1000 of romantic books and you will still be perfectly ignorant of what it is.

ὥστε εἴ τις ἐν Χριστῷ, καινὴ κτίσις· τὰ ἀρχαῖα παρῆλθεν, ἰδοὺ γέγονεν καινά.
A κτίσις is a founding, as distinct from the that-which-is-founded, which is its κτίσμα.
So we couldn't say 'τις ἐστιν καινὴ κτίσις' (and the scripture doesn't say this). The emphasis of ὥστε is placed on the εἴ not the τις. In modern English we'd say:-
"If someone is in Christ, that's a new founding."
And τις can be anyone - Greek doesn't distinguish someone from anyone.
If anyone is in Christ, that's a new founding.
But regarding "founding" English can't derive a figurative sense from the same word we use for cities. So we need a gloss. And before using "creation" as our gloss, we must decide carefully if there is any difference between κτίσις and γένεσις.
A concordance of the LXX has these examples:-

Psalm 104:24
ὡς ἐμεγαλύνθη τὰ ἔργα σου, Κύριε, πάντα ἐν σοφίᾳ ἐποίησας· ἐπληρώθη ἡ
γῆ τῆς κτίσεώς σου.
How many are Your works, O LORD! In wisdom You have made them all; the
earth is full of Your [BLANK].


Tobit 8:5
καὶ ἤρξατο Τωβίας λέγειν· εὐλογητὸς εἶ, ὁ Θεὸς τῶν πατέρων ἡμῶν, καὶ
εὐλογητὸν τὸ ὄνομά σου τὸ ἅγιον καὶ ἔνδοξον εἰς τοὺς αἰῶνας·
εὐλογησάτωσάν σε οἱ οὐρανοὶ καὶ πᾶσαι αἱ κτίσεις σου.
So she got up, and they began to pray and implore that they might be
kept safe. Tobias began by saying, “Blessed are you, O God of our
ancestors, and blessed is your name in all generations forever. Let
the heavens and the whole [BLANK] bless you forever.


Judith 9:12
ναὶ ναὶ ὁ Θεὸς τοῦ πατρός μου καὶ Θεὸς κληρονομίας ᾿Ισραήλ, δέσποτα
τῶν οὐρανῶν καὶ τῆς γῆς, κτίστα τῶν ὑδάτων, βασιλεῦ πάσης κτίσεώς σου,
σὺ εἰσάκουσον τῆς δεήσεώς μου
Please, please, God of my father, God of the heritage of Israel, Lord
of heaven and earth, [BLANK]-er of the waters, King of all your [BLANK],
hear my prayer!

So we can say:-
κτίσις seems to occur more often in the apocrypha and pseudepigrapha
It's strongly associated with the Genesis 1 account of creation. But the example from Judith opens a troubling possibility that it refers to the יְהִ֥י=yehi which is the creative imperative God uses for everything up to Day 5 and excluding the Animals and Man.
Which would mean Paul isn't referring to the person-who-is-in-Christ being a new creation, but the restitutional atonement being tantamount to a new Day being added to the genesis account.

But it's word-salad isn't it? Look at all the conjunctives, conditionals, and reported speech!
[v1] For... For... if... For...not that... but that... so that... So
We know that... for... rather... So... aim to... For... so that
Therefore... But... hope it... known that... cause to... so that... boast about... and not about... For... for God... if... for you... For... because... that... therefore... that... not for... but for... who for... therefore... regard that... though... regarded that... according to... regard that ... Therefore [v16]
Over thirty. If the reader says (for example) "back up a second! verse 11 jumps from particular judgement to evangelism - but I don't agree that evangelism is the only necessary consequence of particular judgement." the argument is needing to skip a productive detour.
It reads like a Gish Gallop https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gish_gallop
This must be rhetorical one-upmanship. They have sent him something similar between 1Cor and 2Cor.
But for it to stand, probably only its concluding point matters, and it must be pretty simple.

For the OP's question, the conjunctions that matter are the last two.
[People can live for Christ] Therefore... we no longer regard Christ according to the flesh... Therefore if anyone is in Christ that's a new founding. [Christ is reconciling the world to himself].
Christ's no longer being in the flesh takes him outside of the scope of the κτίσις of mankind on Day 6. Therefore this must be a new κτίσις, which (as Paul goes on to explain) reconciles the world with him.
Paul's message is to "we who have been trusted with the message of reconciliation" - so presumably bishops and not necessarily anyone lower down. And it might operate at the very simple level of baptising people into Christ, and uniting them by the sacrament into the Church as Christ's body, so they become creatures of this new κτίσις.
What does that mean to them - well, this isn't a passage that explains that. It's about the theological justification of ministry, and presumably the Corinthians held slightly different views on it, or there wouldn't be a letter. Being able to fit what the bishops are doing, and the rituals, into God's plan might be comforting, but it's probably not necessary to their salvation. The consequences of being ἐν Χριστῷ aren't the how-they-get-there.
